# Security: Where are MySQL passwords stored?

Tags: mysql, security

Where are MySQL passwords stored and are they encrypted or even hashed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MySQL passwords are stored in the **user** table of the **mysql** database and are encrypted using it's own algorithm.

You can find more information in [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-names.html)

Comment: The encryption algorithm is essentially SHA1

Answer (score 7):

MySQL passwords for users are stored within MySQL itself; they are stored in the `mysql.user` table. The passwords are hashed by default using the [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function, however there are [other alternatives](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html), though none are plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean the database privileges...  They are stored in the schema and privilege tables.  More specific info is available here:

http://www.grahamwideman.com/gw/tech/mysql/perms/index.htm

Comment: Why would you assume they mean database privileges when the OP specifically states passwords?

Comment: What I meant was that the OP really wanted the table that holds the global database user list (with passwords) and their privileges... not simply a user created "user authentication" table.  Since the question was very vague, it is hard to determine it's true purpose.